# What is Doppelganger's attack when in the HQ?

Tags: legendary-marvel

While playing the scheme *Invade the Daily Bugle News HQ*, I ended up having a single villain in the city: Doppelganger from Maximum Carnage. I drew a Scheme Twist card, which triggers the following event:

> KO a Hero from the HQ. Put the highest [attack] Villain from the city into the HQ space.

This required me to put Doppelganger in the HQ. Doppelganger's card reads:

> Doppelganger's [attack] is equal to the [cost] of the Hero in the HQ space under him.

Now that Doppelganger is in the HQ, what is his attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doppelganger's attack would then be 0.

The [rules insert for Paint the Town Red](http://www.upperdeck.com/OP/RuleBooks/Legendary_Rules-Paint_The_Town_Red.pdf) explicitly covers this case under the Card Clarification for the Invade the Daily Bugle HQ scheme:

> If there is a Villain in the HQ space under Doppelganger, or if Doppelganger is in the HQ, then Doppelganger's [attack] is 0.